# How to recursive change document's settings in Pimcore?

Tags: pimcore

I need to change settings (controller, action and view) in all document in some root. Is some way to do it automatically by admin panel?

Only idea that I have is to write php script to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a function in the root-controller to accomplish this:

```
private function changeDocumentsSettings() {

    foreach ($this->document->getChilds(true) as $child) {

        $child->setController('operator-news');
        $child->setAction('year-list');
        $child->setTemplate('/operatornews/yearlist.php');
        $child->save();

        foreach($child->getChilds(true) as $gchild) {

            $gchild->setController('operator-news');
            $gchild->setAction('item');
            $gchild->setTemplate('/operatornews/item.php');
            $gchild->save();

        }
    }
}
```